# My Devise sessions do work in Internet Explorer (7,8)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise, session-cookies

I use Devise in my Rails 3.1 application to manage sessions. In Safari and Firefox, the user is correctly prompted to login if he attempts to access a page that requires authorization. However, in Internet Explorer (versions 7 and 8), the user is correctly redirected to the login page, but logging in does nothing.

In other words, the username and password are correct, but it appears as if Internet Explorer can not set the session. Cookies are enabled for IE as well.

Has anyone experienced any similar session issues with IE? I just need to know where to look. I have already fought through IE's inability to handle pushState, it seems like IE is pretty difficult to code for.

Internet Explorer 9 seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crossbrowser pushState with hashbang fallback: [History.js](https://github.com/balupton/history.js%5d).

AJAX requests without the XRSF token destroy the devise session, maybe IE is messing this one up with your code.

Comment: Thanks, I am looking into that as we speak.